# react native async - rerendering after user input on multi-language app [missing translation]

Tags: reactjs, react-native, asynchronous, async-await, internationalization

I am trying to update the language of the app from the setting screens. The whole app should change language onLanguageChange. The app does something, because the different fields appear as `[missing '[langCode].[screenName].[fieldName] translation]`, so I am close, but I cannot make the app properly reload and I have literally tried everything available on the internet. It is basically a problem of updating screen on state update, but the app needs some time to load the JSON

Any ideas? here is where I am:

in my settings screen

```
import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';
import i18n, {updateLocale, strings} from '../assets/locales/i18n'

export default function SettingsScreen({navigation}) {

  const {signOut} = React.useContext(global.AuthContext)
  
  const currentLanguage = i18n.locale.toString().substr(0,2);
  const [selectedLanguage, setSelectedLanguage] = useState(currentLanguage);
  const [selectedNotifications, setNotificationsOptions] = useState('On');

const onChangeLanguage = (value) => {
        setSelectedLanguage(value)
        updateLocale(value)
  }

  return (

          <Text style={styles.maintext}>{strings('settingsscreen.Language')}</Text>
          <RNPickerSelect
            placeholder={{}}
            value={selectedLanguage}
            style={pickerSelectStyles}
            onValueChange={(value)=>onChangeLanguage(value)}
            items={[
              { label: 'Español', value: 'es' },
              { label: 'Català', value: 'ca' },
              { label: 'English', value: 'en' },
          ]}
            />

        (...)

        <View style={styles.bubble}>
          <Button title={strings('settingsscreen.signout')} onPress={()=>{
              AsyncStorage.setItem('LANGUAGE', selectedLanguage) && signOut()
          }}
           color='white' />  
        </View>

  );
}
```

and my i18n.js:

```
import * as Localization from 'expo-localization';
import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';
import i18n from 'i18n-js';

// Should the app fallback to English if user locale doesn't exists
i18n.fallbacks = true;
i18n.defaultLocale = 'en';
i18n.locale = 'en';

import en from './en';
import es from './es'; 
import ca from './ca';  

i18n.translations = {
  en,
  es,
  ca,
};

// The method we'll use instead of a regular string
export function strings(name, params = {}) {
  return i18n.t(name, params);
};

// Setting the locale to be used on first render
export const loadLocale = async () => {

  //First we check if there is already a selected variable in AsyncStorage

  asyncSelectedLanguage = await AsyncStorage.getItem('LANGUAGE');
  console.log('async language: ' +asyncSelectedLanguage)

  if (asyncSelectedLanguage!==null) {
    i18n.locale = asyncSelectedLanguage;
  } else {
    i18n.locale = Localization.locale;
  }

  console.log('i18n locale' + i18n.locale)

  
  switch (i18n.locale.toString().substr(0,2)) {
        case 'en': import('./en.json').then(en => {i18n.translations = { en }}); break;
        case 'ca': import('./ca.json').then(ca => {i18n.translations = { ca }}); break;
        case 'es': import('./es.json').then(es => {i18n.translations = { es }}); break;
        default: import('./en.json').then(en => {i18n.translations = { en }}); break;

    }
}

export const updateLocale = async (langcode) => {

  i18n.locale=langcode.toString();
  
  switch (i18n.locale.toString().substr(0,2)) {
        case 'en': import('./en.json').then(en => {i18n.translations = { en }}); break;
        case 'ca': import('./ca.json').then(ca => {i18n.translations = { ca }}); break;
        case 'es': import('./es.json').then(es => {i18n.translations = { es }}); break;
        default: import('./en.json').then(en => {i18n.translations = { en }}); break;

    }
}

export default i18n;
```

Comment: could you please share a sample of  language json file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Simply change i18n.js to:

```
import * as Localization from 'expo-localization';
import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';
import i18n from 'i18n-js';

// Should the app fallback to English if user locale doesn't exists
i18n.fallbacks = true;
i18n.defaultLocale = 'en';
i18n.locale = 'en';

import en from './en';
import es from './es'; 
import ca from './ca';  

i18n.translations = {
  en,
  es,
  ca,
};

// The method we'll use instead of a regular string
export function strings(name, params = {}) {
  return i18n.t(name, params);
};

// Setting the locale to be used on first render
export const loadLocale = async () => {

  //First we check if there is already a selected variable in AsyncStorage

  asyncSelectedLanguage = await AsyncStorage.getItem('LANGUAGE');
  console.log('async language: ' +asyncSelectedLanguage)

  if (asyncSelectedLanguage!==null) {
    i18n.locale = asyncSelectedLanguage;
  } else {
    i18n.locale = Localization.locale;
  }

  
}

export const updateLocale = async (langcode) => {

  i18n.locale=langcode.toString();
  
  
}

export default i18n;
```

Answer (score 0):

In order for the text to change, a re-render must be done. If you need a reload of the entire app you can use [react-native-restart](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-restart). It's kind of rough but it ensures a full re-render of all components. Otherwise you can set your strings in state using the useState and useEffect hooks so the text would re-render. Like so:

```
const [settingScreen, setSettingScreen] = useState(strings('settingsscreen.Language'));

useEffect(()=>{
    setSettingScreen(strings('settingsscreen.Language'))
},[selectedLanguage]);
...
<Text style={styles.maintext}>{settingScreen}</Text>
```

you can also useMemo:

```
const settingScreen = useMemo(() => strings('settingsscreen.Language'),[selectedLanguage]);
...
<Text style={styles.maintext}>{settingScreen}</Text>
```

Comment: thanks Parsa for contributing. I found another solution, I will post below

Comment: Ok. i'll be interested in reading it. re-rendering after language change has been annoying for a while now.